# Update the number of document using spring JPA-Oracle DB

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, nhibernate-mapping

I have a web page where there is one checkbox field and it works fine when user checks few value and save.
But problem occurs when an user again opens the form and uncheck few value and save it. In this situation i want to update the table with the current selected data and delete the unchecked data which is already stored in DB.
I am searching for a solution using Spring JPA to handle it.
Note- On click of save i am getting the entity with the checked data only.

Ex- I have one Employee entity and it has benefits attribut.
In my ui suppose one employee opted(checked)for transport, gym, food and saved.
Again if that employee want to modify his benefits list then he unchecked gym from the list.
In this case on click of save my employee object contains only transport and food.
Now I want my employee update method to delete gym from the benefits table.
I am facing problem bcoz my emplee object contains checked data only.
Let me know if you want more information.

Comment: You need to show us what you are doing and where the problem is. With a description like this no-one will be able to help.

Comment: I have updated my question.please check and provide solution.

Answer (score 0):

ASSUMING you have passed an array/list of items to your controller and passed through to a Service method, the core of your solution MIGHT look something like this:

```
  for (Thing thing : collectionOfThings) {
      if (thing.is_deleted()) {
        thingRepository.deleteById(thing.getId()); // DELETE THOSE FLAGGED/CHECKED FOR DELETION
      } else {
        thingRepository.save(thing); // INSERT OR UPDATE
      }
    }
  }
```

Let me know if this helps.

**[UPDATE responding to comment:]**
So what I called "Thing" might better be called EmployeeBenefit, child of Employee or cross-reference between Employee and Benefit (which is a 3rd static reference table containing the codes and ids for transport, gym, food etc).
It would seem that the solution requires your client form to submit ALL of the EmployeeBenefit records including those marked for deletion, something like this:

```
{ 
  "employeeId": 1001,
  "lastName": "Jones",
  "firsName": "Guillermo",
  "employeeBenefits: [
    {
      "benefitId": 11,
      "is_deleted": false
    },
    {
      "benefitId": 12,
      "is_deleted": false
    },
    {
      "benefitId": 13,
      "is_deleted": true
    },
    {
      "benefitId": 14,
      "is_deleted": true
    },
    {
      "benefitId": 15,
      "is_deleted": false
    },
  ]
}
```

What is your client technology that calls your Spring Boot app?

Comment: My  collectionOfThings doesn't contain the unchecked data. I have updated my questions please check.

Comment: Client side we are using angular

Comment: Template-based or Reactive forms?
Your REST call might look something like this:
resp = await this.http.post(this.BACKEND_URL, instance2Save).toPromise();

...where instance2Save is an instance of a complex object that you marshalled in your form, whose JSON representation resembles the example I gave. 
The point is that the call has to send all of the data including items that "don't exist" or are marked for deletion, not just the EmployeeBenefits that already exist or are to be inserted.

Comment: Mine is reactive form..can you please let me know how to send the unchecked data. I m new to angular

Comment: @zull Your question opens a huge can of worms. For a comprehensive (34 hour) course on Angular which includes Reactive forms, I recommend Maximillian Schwarzmuller's course here: https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2/
For a bare bones course on Angular in the context of database applications with Spring Boot (8 hours of which 2 on Angular, Template-based forms only), I recommend MY course here: https://www.udemy.com/course/intro-db-app-dev-springboot-angular/?referralCode=3AB74AFDA723F00C4762

Comment: @zull I think my course is well-suited to the kinds of things you describe that you are trying to do. There is over an hour of free preview videos.
If you take my course and write to me at hhyde@radinfodesign.com, I can share some unpublished Angular reactive form code with you. Cheers